# TortoiseGit: checked out earlier revision, now revisions after that one are not shown in the log

Tags: git, version-control, tortoisegit

Say I had 4 revisions - A, B, C and D, in order from newest to oldest. I clicked "Show log" in the TortoiseGit context menu, right clicked C and clicked "Switch/Checkout to this". In the window that opened I disabled the "create new branch" option. Then I closed the "Log" window and opened it again. Revisions A and B were no longer in the list, which is a problem because I wanted to get back to revision A.

Any ideas why A and B disappeared?

Comment: TortoiseGit is not Git itself (it appears to just be a fancy GUI front end, though I have never used it) but it seems to share Git's approach here: checking out an old commit in Git gives you what Git calls a "detached HEAD", so that HEAD—which *always* names the current commit—names the old commit. You must `git checkout <branch>` to go back to the newest commit that is the tip of `<branch>`. Meanwhile `git log` defaults to "show me HEAD and older stuff". In command-line Git you can `git log <branch>` to start viewing from the tip of `<branch>`. I have no idea how to do that in TortoiseGit.

Comment: @Stefan Monov, hi, have you get the answer what you want? If yes, please mark it as answer, since it will help others who have similar questions :)

Comment: @Marina-MSFT: The full answer I want is a combination of [MrTux's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40790116) and [torek's comment on my question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40789925/#comment68804132_40789925). But since I can't mark both as accepted, I'm marking neither.

Answer (score 1):

By default TortoiseGit only shows branches which are on the history of your current HEAD (and maybe only relevant for your current selected file/folder).

In order to see other branches you can click on the branch name in the upper left, there you can select a branch to show the log for. Another alternative is the check "Show all branches" in the lower left.

As mentioned above, TortoiseGit also filters the log for the current selected file/folder. If you want to see the whole repository history, check "Whole project" in the lower left.

Comment: I clicked the branch name in the upper left and selected `remote/origin/master` or something like that, and that fixed it, so thanks. But I'm not sure why that worked. I mean, I had *not* switched branch, I had only switched revision. I was still on the master branch, no?

Comment: @StefanMonov: see main-question comment, but in short: no. Once you go to an older commit, you're no longer on the branch!

Answer (score 0):

It is as what saw, if you checkout to C, HEAD will point to C, and **show log** only shows commit histories which behind HEAD by default. You can select **All Branches** checkbox at the bottom-left of log windows, you will find A and B.

```
D---C---B---A
            |
          HEAD  

D---C---B---A
    |
   HEAD
```

If you want to make HEAD re-point to the newest revision A (go back to A), you can close log window -> right click -> **TortoiseGit** -> select **switch/checkout** -> choose the current branch -> you will find HEAD is now re-point to A